# CommandQueue failed: OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY

Tags: python, opencl, pyopencl

I am trying to get pyopencl setup on Ubuntu 18.04 with a Radeon R9 270x garphics card and using amdgpu 19.30 drivers.

```py
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np

platform = cl.get_platforms()[0]
platform_info = platform.get_info(cl.platform_info.VENDOR)
platform_version = platform.get_info(cl.platform_info.VERSION)

device = platform.get_devices()[0]
device_info = device.get_info(cl.device_info.VENDOR)
device_version = device.get_info(cl.device_info.VERSION)

context = cl.Context([device])
queue = cl.CommandQueue(context, device)
```

Whenever I try to run the above code it fails at creating the `CommandQueue` with the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 13, in <module>
    queue = cl.CommandQueue(context, device)
pyopencl._cl.RuntimeError: CommandQueue failed: OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY
```

To install pyopencl I used the instruction from their [install page](https://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/misc.html#installation) and I installed OpenCL through the amdgpu drivers by following the instructions from AMD [here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/amdgpu-installation) and using the legacy version of OpenCL.

I don't think it is a problem with how I installed OpenCL because `platform_version` gives me `'OpenCL 2.1 AMD-APP (2906.7)'` and `device_version` gives me `'OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (2906.7)'` as expected.

Anybody have any ideas of whats going on?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Python bindings, but if you can, I'd try to reproduce the problem in plain C. If it works there, there's something about your Python bindings or the Python process itself that's causing problems. If the C version fails in the same way, there's probably something not right on the OpenCL side.

Answer (score 1):

These exports solved this problem with my 260X:

```
export GPU_FORCE_64BIT_PTR=1
export GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS=1
export GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT=100
export GPU_SINGLE_ALLOC_PERCENT=100
export GPU_MAX_HEAP_SIZE=100
```

Comment: While this may solve the problem, writing about your thinking and how you reached the answer, along with explaining what the code does, always helps the fellow asker. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Unfortunately I found this answer on a forum without further explanations. I re-posted the answer here to give it more visibility. One explanation could be the heap size set to the maximum hence allocating more memory to the GPU but I don't want to risk myself at explaining something wongly.

Comment: @ShivamJha I have no idea if this will work because I no longer have the setup that I used to ask the question. I don't know if I should mark your answer as the accepted answer, but I guess it will remain here for others to look at. From what I remember, the only way I could get OpenCL to work was to downgrade to Ubuntu to 14.xx and I think change the drivers for the GPU.